# Crash while accessing Address passed via ioctl in linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel

I am passing pointer to below structure through ioctl.

```
typedef struct myparam_t {
                int i;
                char *myname;
           }myparam;
```

I allocate memory for myname in the user space before passing the argument.

In the ioctl implementation at kernel space I use copy_from_user() to copy the argument in kspace variable (say kval). call is like  copy_from_user(kval,uval,sizeof(myparam)); kval & uval are of  myparam * type.

Now in ioctl function I have check like -

```
if (uval->myname != NULL) {

}
```

I thought this will result in to kernel crash or panic due to page fault.
However I see different behaviour with different version of kernel.

With 4.1.21 kernel I see no issue with NULL check, But with 4.10.17 kernel I see a page fault that results in to kernel panic.

My question is what might make NULL check working in kernel 4.1.21 ?
Is there a way I can make same code working for 4.10.17 as well ?

Note that I am facing this issue as part of kernel migration. We are trying to migrate from version 4.1.21 to 4.10.17. There may be many instance of such usage in our code base. Hence, if possible, I'd prefer to put a patch in kernel to fix the issue, rather than fixing all such instance.

Thanks
Dipak.

Comment: `Is there a way I can make same code working for 4.10.17 as well?` -
 Do not attempt dereference pointer to user space in the kernel code. Such way your code will work with any kernel. BTW, you have already used `copy_from_user`, why do not use `kval`, which is *in-kernel* pointer, instead of `uval`?

Comment: I get below logs.                              [   14.165378] BUG: unable to handle kernel paging request at 00000000ffe8b608

Comment: @Tsyvarev - I understand we should use macros to access pointers passed from user space. But I am looking at code which is already under production. If I change those code not only new product, existing product which is using older version of kernel has to undergo full test cycle. Hence preference will be given to a solution where pathing a new kernel solves the issue rather than a change in driver.

Comment: I don't get your situation. Do you want to **patch a kernel** instead of fixing error in the driver? But this would introduce problems in other drivers. At least, you would need to re-test the kernel itself. Note, that crash during the user pointer dereference occures when the accessed page is not mapped. This fact depends mainly from the workload (paging cache is quite a complex thing).

Comment: Yes. I want to patch in the kernel instead of in the driver.

Comment: Anyway nothing is final yet. But At least I want to explore this path. I am extremely interested on why same code is working on 4.1.21, but NOT for 4.10.17.

Comment: `I am extremely interested on why same code is working on 4.1.21, but NOT for 4.10.17.` - When one doesn't follow the rules when writing the code, it is known as "**undefined behaviour**": wrong code could work sometimes, and, with a very little change, does not work. And this behaviour is badly reproducable: it could work on one machine, but doesn't work on another.

Comment: @ Tsyvarev . I agree with you. But this code is in production. Hence I am doubting if it is working just because of luck. I wonder if there is something that makes it working for 4.1.21.